# Better control to enter managed metadata tags

Tags: 2013, tagging

My users don't like the default control for exploring/entering managed metadata. Specifically the way it has a scroll bar, but then you have to page between using the clunky arrows. it is very non-fluid and awkward.

Does anyone know how to change the control for entering tags? Are there good premade, plug-n-play solutions out there?

Answer (score 0):

their is no OUT of box way to control this Term Store. I think it is pretty fine.

AFAIK, even no 3rd party tool available which handle the MM term store entries or give you the interface for it.

Only term store administrator browse to that page, i think, it is easy to trained them.

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2013/archive/2013/01/31/term-store-management-in-sharepoint-2013-how-to-s-for-common-actions.aspx